# How to set LOCAL_LDFLAGS/LOCAL_CPPFLAGS with cmake in ndk?

Tags: gradle, cmake, android-ndk

How to set LOCAL_CPPFLAGS/LOCAL_CFLAGS/LOCAL_LDFLAGS with cmake? I want to reduce so size, but the tutorials i have read are all about mk files. What should I do in cmakelists.txt?

I directly set LOCAL_CPPFLAGS/LOCAL_CFLAGS/LOCAL_LDFLAGS, but it seems not work.

```
set(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS "${LOCAL_CPPFLAGS} -ffunction-sections,-fdata-sections")
set(LOCAL_CFLAGS "${LOCAL_CFLAGS} -ffunction-sections,-fdata-sections")
set(LOCAL_LDFLAGS  "${LOCAL_LDFLAGS} -Wl,--gc-sections,--icf=safe")
```

Comment: If description `Use 'LOCAL_CPPFLAGS' to specify flags for C++ only.` fully reveals meaning of the `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS` variable (taken from [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)), then CMake equivalent is [CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html) variable. Equivalent for `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` when build a shared library is [CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html). Since `LOCAL_CFLAGS` affects both on C and C++, you need to set both `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that using something like this:

```
target_compile_options(mytarget PRIVATE -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections)
target_link_libraries(mytarget -Wl,--gc-sections,--icf=safe)
```

Note that `-ffunction-sections` has been enabled by default for a while when using the NDK's Clang. And if you're using NDK r19c or later I believe `-fdata-sections` is enabled by default too. So only the linker flags should be necessary for you to specify explicitly.

Comment: Note that as of 3.13 you can use `target_link_options` instead of `target_link_libraries`: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html